# Hide Siri's window on macOS Sierra

Tags: siri, macos

After asking Siri a question on macOS Sierra -- her response window just stays pinned in the upper right corner.

Is there a keyboard shortcut or another siri command to hide that window without having to click the small "x" button?  Maybe a way to make it automatically close after some time has passed?

Comment: With type to Siri enabled, typing "Goodbye" or "Disappear" hides the windows. (Commands translated from another language.)

Comment: It's ridiculous... the popup remains even when your screensaver activates.  What is the point of a voice assistant that you have to use the keyboard/mouse to close?! To be fair, Google assist on Android phones is similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without Type to Siri enabled, you may close the Siri window at any time by pressing the `ESC` key. However, I am unaware of a way to automatically close Siri after some time has passed or by using the keyboard with Type to Siri.

Comment: There's a bug.  If you enable Type To Siri, there's no way to close the Siri box.  Pressing ESC has no effect.  It's obnoxious.  The only way to close the box is to swipe it away with the trackpad.

Comment: Yep, a bug and Apple will never fix it, they'll just move on to the next OS version as they do. Suggestion below to type "nevermind" works but that's extra typing, [x] nofun. ESC doesn't work, Cmd-. doesn't work, and typing anything will run a search. The only option other than click on the siri window close, is to click somewhere else on the screen and the siri window will autoclose after about 5 seconds.

Answer (score 7):

If you've enabled "Type To Siri" and find that ESC doesn't close the window, try typing "nevermind" and hitting enter. In my case, Siri replies "ok" and the window closes.

A further refinement is to set up a keyboard shortcut for nevermind "nmd" to save on the typing.  "bye" also closes the window but Siri says it is "Nice talking with you" and that is more annoying than "ok".  Of course you can also suppress Siri read responses, and you probably have if you're using "Type To Siri".

Comment: Thanks, 'nevermind' works, but is extra work unfortunately. I also tried "go pound sand" and "go jump in a lake". The other option is to click somewhere else on the screen and go on with your Mac life - after 5 seconds the siri window will slide back into the obscurity from where it came.

Comment: Go to `Keyboard Settings` and create a shortcut from `nvm` to `nevermind`. This will save you time.

Comment: Another option is to write "quit" which I found quicker to write than "bye" for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (besides the `esc` key) is `cmd`+`.`.

This is useful if you're on a MacBook Pro with Touch Bar, and you're in an app where the `esc` has turned into something else (like while playing full-screen video).

Comment: Did not work for me (macbook pro with touch bar)

Answer (score 0):

If you type "bye", Siri replies briefly and then closes

Answer (score -3):

there is a workaround for that which actually works pretty awesome. i hope its ok to post the link:

http://www.macworld.com/article/3096187/macs/how-to-make-siri-activate-when-you-say-hey-siri-to-your-mac-running-macos-sierra.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.